# Is it even possible to access underlying Android (or native) members of any UI element?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I've been trying to accessing the underlying Android members of some UI elements, and may be because I am pretty new on nativescript, I have not been able to access them reliably. The only thing that allows me to access the underlying Android members is the ActionBar.

A simple test is on https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=3K75iv&v=7

As you can tell, the Page, Label, Button and ScrollView all returns an undefined when I tried to access the android property. I don't know what makes ActionBar so special that it actually defy my expectation and returns the native Android component. **BTW, I did try using the "nativeView" property, but just as I expected, it behaved exactly like the android property.**

On top of that, why the heck some elements need the $el property to access _nativeView, but some don't?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to make a regular JS NativeScript project and all the components return the android property as expected. So, it appears that the problem has to do with how Vue is being used for NativeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorect, with Vue reference you will access native member as follows

```
this.$refs.page1.nativeView.android
```

Comment: I changed it to this.$refs.page1.nativeView.android, but it did not make any difference. It still returns undefined:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=3K75iv&v=16

Comment: Of course, the native member will not be available on mounted event. You should wait for loaded event of component itself. For example loaded event of Page will mostly guarantee the availability of native member of all the child views and the page itself.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! This is exactly what I need!